# Why Can't `DSolve` Find a Solution for this ODE with y[-x]

Tags: differential-equations

I wanted to find a accuracy solution of the following ODE.

$$y'(x)+y(x)=-y(-x).$$

But when I try to use `DSolve` as follows

```
DSolve[y'[x] + y[x] == -y[-x], y[x], x]
```

I get a warning message:

> DSolve::litarg: To avoid possible ambiguity, the arguments of the dependent variable in {y[x]+(y^[Prime])[x]==-y[-x]} should literally match the independent variables.

How can I solve this equation with $y(-x)$?

Comment: As the warning message says, the argument to the dependent variable must be exactly the same as in the last parameter. This is like as if you wrote `DSolve[ y'[x]+1==y[z],y[x],x]` . May be if you explain what you want to write `y[-x]` in there instead of `y[x]` it will help.

Comment: Is that equation even an ODE? I don't think $y(-x)$ is an allowed term in an "ordinary" differential equation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put `g[x] =f[-x]`, change the sign `x` in the equation, then we get a system of two equations that has a solution

```
 DSolve[{f'[x] + f[x] + g[x] == 0, -g'[x] + g[x] + f[x] == 
   0}, {f, g}, x]

Out[]= {{f -> Function[{x}, (1 - x) C[1] - x C[2]], 
  g -> Function[{x}, x C[1] + (1 + x) C[2]]}}
```

From the condition `g[x] =f[-x]`we find `C[1] = C[2]`

Comment: You could also add `f'[0] + 2f[0] == 0` as in @AccidentalFourierTransform's answer.

Comment: Thank you. We can also use the condition `g[x]=f[-x]`

Comment: How did you get this: `-g'[x] + g[x] + f[x] == 0` ?

Comment: @user36313 If  we change sign `x->-x ` then `y'[x]->-y'[-x]=-g'[x]`.

Comment: Thank you, but I still do not get it. If we change `x->-x`, then by literal substitution it should be `y'[x]->y'[-x]`. Why is it not so?

Comment: @user36313 Are you really don't get it that $\frac {dy}{dx}$ turns to $\frac {dy}{-dx}$?

Answer (score 10):

Take
$$
y'(x)+y(x)+y(-x)=0
$$

Write the same equation, with $x\to-x$:
$$
y'(-x)+y(x)+y(-x)=0
$$
and subtract the two equations:
$$
y'(x)-y'(-x)=0
$$

Integrate this equation:
$$
y(x)+y(-x)=2y(0)
$$
and plug this back into the initial equation:
$$
y'(x)+2y(0)=0
$$
with solution
$$
y(x)=y(0)(1-2x)
$$

It is easy to check that this solves the initial equation:

```
y'[x] + y[x] == -y[-x] /. y -> ((-2 y[0] # + y[0]) &)
(* True *)
```

I hope I didn't mess up the algebra though, so please double check everything.